# Voicemail recordings and transcription email fall under GDPR

Tags: united-states, gdpr, germany

A client calls, leaves a voicemail with his name and number.

A vendor calls, leaves account information and address information. This call is also transcribed and sent via email.

The above are common communications left to individual employees' voicemail.
Do these fall under GDPR protection laws, and how are they to be handled?

I understand when a consumer calls, they  are informed that call may be recorded, but with the above type of communication is this implicitly assumed?

Comment: I'm aware there is already an answer, but your question is actually too broad. You might want to read the [GDPR](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679) so you can decide how you would like to narrow down the question. For instance, it is inaccurate to presume that GDPR is applicable in all instances of clients' calls and vendors' calls. As for how those communications are to be handled, the GDPR contains literally dozens of pages/extensive articles addressing various aspects the handling of that data entails.

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you describe is entirely expected. Leaving contact details on voicemail is one of the chief functions of voicemail, and such data definitely falls under the GDPR.

Now, under the GDPR this is not a problem. The customer left that data intentionally for you in order to be contacted. That is sufficient reason for you to have that data. However, all other GDPR policies should still apply. You shouldn't keep that voicemail for an unreasonable amount of time. That's not bad business practice either: erase the voicemail once you called back, so you know that call is handled. The customer may request that you share that voicemail, per the GDPR, and you'll need to make sure that the request comes from the person who made the call. But that's luckily something you only need to do if anyone ever asks.